# Error reading file '/media/xml/example.xml': failed to load external entity "/media/xml/example.xml"

Tags: python, xml, django, lxml

In my Django project i try to load external xml file and find some data in it.
But I get an error message.

```
Error reading file '/media/xml/example.xml': failed to load external entity "/media/xml/example.xml"
```

Here is my code:

```
xml_file = etree.parse('/media/xml/example.xml')
find_data = etree.XPath("Some text")
data_result = find_data(xml_file)
```

Can you help me with it? Thank You.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend you Beautifulsoup, it is so cool and convinient to use:

```
dir = '/'.join([settings.BASE_DIR, 'media', 'xml/example.xml'])
abs_path = os.path.realpath(dir)
soup = BeautifulSoup(open(abs_path)) #<-- here you can now read/search thru xml file

for row in soup.find_all('row'):
    print row.find('name').text
```

if your xml looks like:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='us-ascii'?>
<root>
   <row>
     <name>Wake up to BeautifulSoup!</name>
   </row>
</root>
```

you will get:

```
Wake up to BeautifulSoup!
```

the docs is [here](http://www.crummy.com/software/BeautifulSoup/bs4/doc/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer, i tried to open XML file in the python invirement by BeautifulSoup ` xml = '/var/www/hispatour/media/xml/example.xml' ` `soup = BeautifulSoup(open(xml))` and answer was _Killed_ error, same result in Django.  I have the big XML file (about 90000 strings). So now i try to do this by ElementTree